# Interface for println(String)

Tags: java, println, duck-typing, method-signature

I'd like to write Java code (say, a method) that will print some lines.

The object onto which to print shall be provided by the caller. I'd like my code to *not* care what exactly that object is and simply call that objects' `println()` or `println(String)` methods. It should work whether that object is a `java.io.PrintStream` (e.g. `System.out`) or a `java.io.PrintWriter` (e.g. constructed by the caller with `new PrintWriter(System.out)` or `new PrintWriter(new ByteArrayOutputStream())`).

This would be easy if the potential classes of a "printlineable" object would share some interface that mandated the `println()` and `println(String)` methods. However they don't.

So what do I put into the signature to receive such an object without violating the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) by writing twice what is essentially the same implementation, just with swapped out types (as I would have to when simply overloading the function)?

```
public void sayHello( ??? outThingy) {
    outThingy.println("Hello World");
    outThingy.println();
    // This just a minimal example.
    // The real implementation might be more involved
    // and non-trivial, so that avoiding duplication
    // becomes a real concern.
};


// sayHello should be usable like this:

sayHello(System.out);


// but also like this:

baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
pw = new PrintWriter(baos)

sayHello(pw);

pw.flush();
System.out.println(baos.toString());
```

Or should the fact that `PrintStream` and `PrintWriter` don't share such an interface be treated as indication that they aren't interchangeable in the regard of providing a way to print lines? (Rather than that being some kind of historical oversight back when these classes were specified.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be interested in a different, more functional approach. Instead of worrying about what each type offers and how to find a common `interface` between them, you can achieve the same thing with less code by using a `Consumer` and a `Runnable` as representations of the `println` methods.

```
// This is the common class
class FuncPrinter {
  private Consumer<String> consumer;
  private Runnable runnable;

  public FuncPrinter(PrintWriter writer) {
    consumer = writer::println;
    runnable = writer::println;
  }

  public FuncPrinter(PrintStream stream) {
    consumer = stream::println;
    runnable = stream::println;
  }

  public void println(String line) {
    consumer.accept(line);
  }

  public void println() {
    runnable.run();
  }
}

class Talker {    
  void sayHello(FuncPrinter fp) {
    fp.println("Hello World");
    fp.println();
  }
}
```

And you could use it like so:

```
Talker t = new Talker();

FuncPrinter fp = new FuncPrinter(System.out);
t.sayHello(fp);

ByteArrayOutputStream ostream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(ostream);
fp = new FuncPrinter(pw);
t.sayHello(fp);

fp = new FuncPrinter(
  line -> System.out.println(line),
  () -> System.out.println(42));
t.sayHello(fp);
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would just to overload the method with a version that accepts a `PrintWriter` and a version that accepts a `PrintStream`:

```
public void sayHello(PrintStream outThingy) {
    outThingy.println("Hello World");
    outThingy.println();
};
public void sayHello(PrintWriter outThingy) {
    outThingy.println("Hello World");
    outThingy.println();
};
```

Comment: Is there a way without violating [the DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)? With the short example code I used for the question, that isn't an issue, but my real function is more involved.

Comment: @das-g Yes: `void sayHello(PrintStream out) { PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(out); sayHello(pw); pw.flush(); }`, then implement the `void sayHello(PrintWriter out)` method.

Comment: Heh, my current code (that I'd like to refactor) is actually somewhat like this, @Andreas: It currently accepts an OutputStream and always wraps it in a PrintWriter.

Comment: The motivation for my question was that I was wondering whether my code should use a PrintStream for the wrapping instead. (And maybe not wrap the object at all, if it already is a PrintStream?) My conclusion was that it should better be the caller's responsibility to decide that. Thus I'd like to refactor my code in a way so that the caller already provides a generic "thing" that my code can `println()` on without any wrapping, but maybe that's not possible, without imposing new interfaces upon the caller, that current Java standard library classes don't implement.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way you could do it and at least keep the client of the `outThingy` DRY. But, you'll make a trade off for effectively having a couple WET classes. Still, the amount of code is minimal.

```
// Printer allows for a common interface
interface Printer {
  void println(String line);
  void println();
}

// Used with PrintStream
class StreamPrinter implements Printer {
  private PrintStream ps;

  public StreamPrinter(PrintStream ps) {
    this.ps = ps;
  }

  @Override
  public void println(String line) {
    ps.println(line);
  }

  @Override
  public void println() {
    ps.println();
  }
}

// Used with PrintWriter
class TypeWriter implements Printer {
  private PrintWriter pw;

  public TypeWriter(PrintWriter pw) {
    this.pw = pw;
  }

  @Override
  public void println(String line) {
    pw.println(line);
  }

  @Override
  public void println() {
    pw.println();
  }
}

class Talker {
  // This class doesn't care!
  void sayHello(Printer printer) {
    printer.println("Hello world");
    printer.println();
  }
}
```